# PNG images are viewed by Firefox

Tags: firefox, shotwell, png, image-viewers

General problem start with seting default application for viewing png files as a Shotwell. If your default image viewer is Shotwell Viewer, your PNG files will be opened with Mozilla Firefox.

Why is that?

I mention that if I choose different viewer as Image Viewer problem solves.

Answer (score 1):

How did you set the default viewer ?

Can you try this `xdg-mime default shotwell.desktop image/png`